# PHP two equal max values

Tags: php

I have some PHP that I want to change a variable based on the max result of an array. I need it to set a message if there is a tie on the max value, i'm almost there (results return correct apart from if there is a tie)

Any help appreciated :)

```
$ex_res = ($ex1+$ex2)/2;
$ag_res = ($ag1+$ag2)/2;
$con_res = ($con1+$con2)/2;
$em_res = ($em1+$em2)/2;
$op_res = ($op1+$op2)/2;


$highest = max($ex_res ,$ag_res, $con_res, $em_res, $op_res);
if ($highest == $ex_res) {$dom_trait = "EXTROVERSION";}else
if ($highest == $ag_res) {$dom_trait = "AGREEABLENESS";}else
if ($highest == $con_res) {$dom_trait = "CONSCIENTIOUSNESS";}else
if ($highest == $em_res) {$dom_trait = "EMOTIONAL";}else
if ($highest == $op_res) {$dom_trait = "OPENNESS";}else { 
$dom_trait="NONE";
}
```

Comment: what are you actually asking?

Comment: The question is what result do you need / expect when for example `$ex_res` and `$ag_res` are the same?

Comment: @DanielBürckner OP wants to display a message if any of the values are equal

Comment: @ADyson: Any of the values or just the highest of the values?

Comment: Karl the calculation of what is highest is done within the `max()` function, and if two values are considered equal, if simply returns the first one it was given. Therefore if there's a tie it's not transparent to you. If you're comparing entirely numbers then it may be simple enough to just write the comparison code yourself. That way you can explicitly check for equal values and act accordingly.

Comment: @DanielBürckner it says "a tie on the max value" but really that makes no sense. There is only one "max" value as defined by the function. Either way, see my comment above. It's not possible to use the max() function to check for equal values under any definition. The solution is for OP to make some custom code to check it.

Answer (score 2):

So this is your value :

```
$ex_res = ($ex1+$ex2)/2;
$ag_res = ($ag1+$ag2)/2;
$con_res = ($con1+$con2)/2;
$em_res = ($em1+$em2)/2;
$op_res = ($op1+$op2)/2;
```

To know if you have a tie, you can just build an array and use `array_count_value()` to check is the same value is present multiple time :

```
$array = array($ex_res, $ag_res, $con_res, $em_res, $op_res);
```

For the example, let's say you have `$array = array(10, 20, 20, 15, 18);`

```
$array_count_value = array_count_values($array);
```

The output is :

```
array (size=4)
    10 => int 1
    20 => int 2
    15 => int 1
    18 => int 1
```

Now just do what you already do to get the `$hightest` value :

```
$highest = max($ex_res ,$ag_res, $con_res, $em_res, $op_res);
```

So here with my example you have :

```
$highest = max(10, 20, 20, 15, 18);
$highest = 20;
```

So to know if there is a tie, just check if you have some value > 1 :

```
foreach ($array_count_value as $result => $count) {
    if ($count > 1 && $result === $highest) {
        echo "Tie for highest value " . $result;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** : as suggested in the comment, you can do this too :

```
if ($array_count_value[$highest] > 1)
    echo "Tie for highest value " . $highest;
```

---

With my example, the output is : `Tie for highest value 20`

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I suggested an edit to your answer which also checks if the duplicate value is the highest. I believe this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: It's better to use `&&` as apposed to `AND` as `&&` has a higher precedence than `AND` as explaned on [php.net example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: Wouldn't `$array_count_value[$highest] > 1` be easier than looping?

Comment: You also use `$highest` but never set it - this could be useful to OP

Comment: this works great - annoyingly i didn't realise that a solution might have an issue with non-integers (since my results are averages it kicks off sometimes)